# Debug Bodymovin Extension Crash during Export w/ Expressions

Tags: after-effects, bodymovin

It appears that bodymovin will crash with render failed randomly during our export.

Is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that we're able to debug the extension using:

`chrome://inspect/#devices`

And configuring the port addresses with the following

[image]

There I can verify that the reason it is failing is due to a broken `else` statement as  it states it inside of the `console`.

Bodymovin uses `Esprima.js` in order to parse the expressions, and if there is a syntax error, it may crash.

[image]